# Finding the positive numbers count in an ECMAScipt array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

All I am trying to achieve is better use of built-in ES functions.

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3];

function countPositiv(p, c, i, a)
{ 
  if(c > 0){
    return p+1; 
  } else {
    return p;
  }
}

var positiv = arr.reduce(countPositiv, 0);

console.log(positiv);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful reviews.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much to review, it looks ok. I would just do it inline, and there is no need to list arguments you are not using:

```
var positiv = arr.reduce(function(acc, x) {
  return x > 0 ? acc + 1 : acc;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using `filter` and `length`. `filter` creates an array comprising of values where the callback returned `true`. In this case, when `v > 0`. And since `filter` returns an array, we have access to `length`.

```
let positiveNumbersCount = arr.filter(v => v > 0).length;
```